# How to add Color Picker control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating WPF Application.
I am not able to find `ColorPicker` control.
Is there any Dynamic Linked Library is there to add color picker control in my VS 2010. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/99072

Please download toolkit from above link.

refer in your project solution, in tool box select the dll from choose item.

the color picker control get added in automatically in toolbox.

Let me know,.